# How to change Details in System Settings

Tags: settings, system

I want to make my own linux distribution based on Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to know how can I change the logo picture with Ubuntu in System Settings >> Details >> Overview.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just edit this picture :)

```
/usr/share/unity-control-center/ui/UbuntuLogo.png
```

Comment: yep, that the image showed in details dialog. Just for info, It cames with `unity-control-center` package.